# Rcpp::checkUserInterrupt() in OpenMP parallelized loop throwing stack imbalance

Tags: openmp, rcpp

I've placed `Rcpp::checkUserInterrupt()` commands throughout several functions which are called sequentially within an OpenMP-parallelized `for` loop. Everything works great when I run OpenMP scheduling with just a single thread. However, when I use multiple threads, I sporadically (often) encounter a stack imbalance regardless of the scheduling paradigm used. This is without interrupting the session. When I interrupt the session, I either get thrown a stack imbalance error, or the R session freezes, or the R session aborts. There's really no rhyme or reason that I can find to what happens when.

Can `Rcpp::checkUserInterrupt()` be used within an OpenMP-parallelized function? If so, what is best practice?

Comment: No as it violates the first rule of OpenMP with R: never ever calls back to R in any form.  An (exported) Rcpp function still contains "traces" of R.

Comment: Thanks again @DirkEddelbuettel!  Are these rules in your book?  I should probably buy your book.

Comment: Some things are in the book, some things are in the vignettes, some things are in the vignettes of other packages (for this, see `RcppParallel`), some things are in various SO answers here, or in mailing list answers, or in GitHub issues, or in presentation slides, ...  It's a journey, and there are no shortcuts.